# Best practice when handling values read from a file

Tags: java, validation, exception, input

I was wondering, if for example I read parameters for objects from a file, given this method, what is the best way to handle these exceptions? My class `Auto` has 4 parameters `model, year, km, price`:

```
public static Auto read(BufferedReader br) {
        String model = br.readLine();
        int year = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int km = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        double price = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
        return new Auto(model, an, km, pret);
}
```

From my readings and what I found as best practice, given the posibility that the user may write invalid input to the file such as `null` for `year` or something like that, I think it would be best something like this:

```
public static Auto read(BufferedReader br) throws IOException, NumberFormatException{
        String model = br.readLine();
        int year = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int km = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        double price = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
        return new Auto(model, an, km, pret);
}
... // in main
try {
...
} catch (IOException e) {
     //something
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
     throw new RuntimeException("Parsing to int/double failed, invalid input. Try again.", e);
}
```

Is my approach good enough?

Comment: Do you have to manually read this from a file or can you use a library for the job? Also, can you enforce a specific format of the file?

Comment: "what is the best way to handle these exceptions" - that's really context-specific. If this *is* a hand-written or manually-edited file then *maybe* you should be forgiving and list all broken lines as warnings and otherwise continuing. If it's really *expected* to be valid, then failing hard may well be the best course of action - often continuing with only partially-valid data is much worse than stopping entirely. We can't advise you on what's best, because it depends on your app, which we don't know anything about.

Comment: @JonSkeet This is just a scenario used for practice, given a file with many parameteres given for objects(I don't know how many), I have to read them and in the case of some invalid input(such as null for parsing), should I go over it or crash the program with a runtime exception. I am trying to understand what standards should be used for production code.

Comment: My point is that the decision of "should I go over it or crash the program" is a choice that depends on the application. It's like asking "Should I use a string, or an integer?" without any context of data you're trying to represent. Production code should do the right thing for the application - which will sometimes be crashing fast and hard, and will sometimes be skipping (but highlighting) the broken data. There's no one-size-fits-all rule.

Comment: How about these for rules-of-thumb: 1) never crash intentionally unless there's truly no way to keep going; 2) if at first you think there's no way to keep going, _think again_; 3) bad input by humans is never an acceptable excuse to crash production-standard code.